# Parsed HTML using Python of a web page is different than the actual page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I need to get and store the PM2.5 and PM10 values from the table in https://app.cpcbccr.com/AQI_India/. I use BeautifulSoup4 to scrape the web page, but the parsed HTML I got is different from the actual page. For example, I get this

[image]

instead of this.

[image]

I wrote the required code to get the table rows and table data etc., but since my parsed HTML is missing rows of the table body, it couldn't find them, so now I only have this to see my parsed HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://app.cpcbccr.com/AQI_India/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

with open("Desktop/soup.html", "a") as dumpfile:
    dumpfile.write(str(soup))
```

How can I get all of the table? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. I have implemented the data scraping script for https://app.cpcbccr.com/AQI_India/ using the API way. Using requests you can hit the API and it will send back the result which you have to convert in to **JSON** format.

```
import json
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
def scrap_air_quality_index():
    
    payload = 'eyJzdGF0aW9uX2lkIjoic2l0ZV8zMDEiLCJkYXRlIjoiMjAyMC0wNy0yNFQ5OjAwOjAwWiJ9:'

    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.post('https://app.cpcbccr.com/aqi_dashboard/aqi_all_Parameters',data=payload,verify=False)
    result = json.loads(response.text) 
    extracted_metrics = result['metrics']
    print(extracted_metrics)
```

I have checked the API calls in the network section where i got the API url https://app.cpcbccr.com/aqi_dashboard/aqi_all_Parameters which i'm using for getting the data using an additional mandatory parameter which is a payload without this you will not be able to get the data. You can leverage script and add saving of data(refer screenshot [image: Result of the script printed on the console]) to .csv or excel file.

1. Image of API URL
   [image: api url from website]
2. Image of json result of metrics.
   [image: json result of metrics]

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks. I have one more question. I am trying to get more than one days' data. I am able to change the date, but as long as I keep the `payload` the same, the data doesn't change. Is there a way to get the `payload` automatically?

Comment: In that case you have to go with Beautiful soup way because this API request method is POST for which everything should be present  before hand to get the response.

Comment: Or is there any way I can collect and store each days' payload beforehand, then I can send POST requests accordingly? Because I could not find any way using BS4.